# Wait for a non child Process to end

Tags: go, process, watchdog

Hi I am working on a simple code that will monitor a process and restart the process in case the process crashes. I have written a small sample code.

This is my external process

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    for {
        time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Println("hello")
    }
}
```

This is the code that monitors it.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    p, e := os.FindProcess(<processid>)
    fmt.Println(e)
    fmt.Println(p.Wait())
    fmt.Println("done")
}
```

The challenge here is that since the first process is not a child process of the second one, it does not wait and directly exits. 
Please let me know if anyone has any ideas around this.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to use go-ps? https://github.com/mitchellh/go-ps
Or gops? https://github.com/google/gops

Answer (score 0):

Monitoring process exits because `p.Wait()` does not block.

From the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Process.Wait):

> On most operating systems, the Process must be a child of the current
>   process or an error will be returned.

You can perhaps poll the process pool to check if the process still exists.

Comment: Do you know any mechanism for polling, pipes is one way to do, but would like to implement a less complicated solutiom

Comment: You can try one of the packages listed in the comment above. For example, use go-ps and have a loop intermittently check the process executable to see if the process is still running. Pipes might be complicated but they'll be a better solution.